# scipy's cdist incompatible with Sympy symbols

Tags: python, optimization, scipy, sympy

I realised today that sympy's matrix symbols in a vector (for multiple partial element-wise derivatives over a covariance matrix) was incompatible with scipy's cdist during the the optimize.minimize process, as it assumes actual use of numbers when making the function call (fair enough).

It first runs into the issue that the expression can't be converted to a float, as it contains sympy symbols

```
TypeError: can't convert expression to a float
```

Followed by a very long list of repeated:

```
During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred: 
SystemError: <built-in function hasattr> returned a result with an error set
```

Is there any built-in way of utilising both cdist and substitution by way of sympy's symbols, or is the only option here to implement a custom implementation of cdist that can deal with symbols? Not that it matters, but cdist method I'm using is squared euclidean.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

As you've found, scipy.distance.cdist does not handle arbitrary objects. You'll need to implement Euclidean norm yourself.

Answer (score 1):

You can get the norm of a SymPy matrix expression by first converting it to an explicit matrix object, then using the norm method.

```
In [13]: A = MatrixSymbol("A", 1, 3)

In [14]: A.as_explicit().norm()
Out[14]:
   __________________________
  ╱      2        2        2
╲╱  │A₀₀│  + │A₀₁│  + │A₀₂│
```